# javascript detect if browser has turned off CORS

Tags: javascript

there is a way to bypass CORS error while turning on browser like:

```
google-chrome-stable --disable-web-security
```

or just use some plugin:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf

is there a way to check if CORS is ON/OFF using javascript on a webpage ?

Comment: Cors is a server setting, not a browser setting

Comment: I’m not sure what this plugin does but you can’t change a server response .... So I wonder what problem you try to solve?

Comment: well if you dont see what plugin does why you reply then ?

Comment: @Kokodoko saying it's not a browser setting is completely wrong. The server is the one setting the response headers, but the browser is the one responsible to follow the security rules - and it can indeed be disabled as the question clearly and correctly explains (on chrome for example). And the question even provides two ways of doing it, one through a native option in the command line, and the other through a plugin that just "hacks" the response.

Comment: Well thanks for clarifying instead of using a hostile tone :) I wasn't aware you could change the CORS response in the client using a plugin/cli.  It seems really bad practice, since it will allow malicious requests to be made. I still also don't know why OP even wants this.

Answer (score 2):

Since turning off CORS isn't really a standard thing I don't believe that there's a way to do it without making an actual request. However, you could always try making a request to google and seeing if it errors, however I'm not sure this is the best coding practice.

Comment: well I want to avoid this ;)